# Getting frames from a video in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a component where if a person selects a video from their image gallery, that the video will display(not playing) along with all the frames from the video. The user will then select from the frames to set as the video thumbnail, much like how instagram handles in when selecting videos to upload. Struggling to find a package for this for React Native.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: have you done this

Answer (score 2):

[ffmpeg-kit-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme) can be used to generate video frames with this command:

```
FFmpegKit.execute('-i '+videoUri + " -r 1/1 "+outputFileUri+".png")
```

Worked for me

Happy coding but manage your tears

Comment: where is it come from this variable 'videoUri'
Share complete code to me